# Scheduler not updating textview periodically

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to update the text in textview from `SchedulerExecutiveService`. But strangely, textview is updated only the first time and not after that.

```
ScheduledExecutorService textService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    textService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("sg", "Logging Seconds");
            textStart.setText("Dyanamic text here.");
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This code is working properly if I remove `textStart.setText(..)` part.

Comment: why are you using `Executors` for such thing? it is like using a cannon to kill a fly... why dont you use `Handler`s?

Comment: @pskink: Not sure whether or not we can use `Handler` for performing periodic task.

Comment: see postDelayed method

Comment: IMO, it could be easily done with RxJava, RxAndroid and `interval()` operator. Most of modern Android apps already have dependency to these libraries, because they're useful for asynchronous operations. As @pskink aleready said, `Executors` are too heavy for this and you have to deal with concurrency issues by yourself. You can do this if you really  understand it or have a lot of time.

Comment: @piotr.wittchen: Can you please direct me towards any sample code that would help me using `RxAndroid` and `interval()`. That would be very helpful.

Comment: @Shubham Check out this article: http://blog.freeside.co/2015/01/29/simple-background-polling-with-rxjava/ . In your case, you should subscribe on `Schedulers.io()` thread and observe on `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`. You can adjust sample in this article to your needs and update `TextView` every given time interval.

Comment: @piotr.wittchen: looks very good. that helped me a lot. Just could not figure out to make observable stop emitting items. Using `Observable
                .interval(0,1,TimeUnit.SECONDS,Schedulers.io())'.

Comment: You can try to play with `takeUntil(...)` operator from RxJava, so your Observable will be emitting data until second Observable emits specific value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView textStart;
    private int i= 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textStart = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStart);

        ScheduledExecutorService textService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        textService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i("sg", "Logging Seconds");
                textStart.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        i++;
                        textStart.setText(""+i);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

It's working fine for me.

Comment: Accepting this, as this answers my original question. As mentioned in comments, using `ScheduledExecutorService` is definitely one of the worst ways of doing what I intended to do. I did it using `RxJava`. Please check my answer below for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `textStart.setText("Dyanamic text here.");` line inside `runOnUiThread` because `scheduleAtFixedRate` Runnable called on background Thread from where not possible to access UI elements.

Comment: But then why is it able to update the text in `TextView` the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You must update your textview in runonUiThread.

I have used Timer to update my textview. Try this, it will help you.

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

 @Override
public void run() {

 mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   timertap.setText(timer_count + "");
  }
 });


 }
}, 1000,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally achieved the same result in a very light weight manner using `Rx`. Check the code below.

```
subscription = Observable
            .interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Long aLong) {
                    int millis = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    String time = String.format("%d:%d sec",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) -
                                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
                    );
                    textStart.setText(time);
                }
            });
```